# How to show icons during drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, icons, netbeans-platform

I am working on some NetBeans platform app, and i am currently stuck on some detail in Visual Library. Ok, here is problem. I have Visual Editor for my app, with pallet, scene and everything works great, just there is a problem when i am dragging icons from pallet to scene. They are not displayed during drag event, i would like to create that effect, can someone help on this?

Answer (score 5):

I do this in two phases:

1) Create a screenshot (an image) of a palette element. I create the screenshot lazily and then cache it within the view. To create the screenshot, you can use this snippet:

```
screenshot = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);// buffered image
// creating the graphics for buffered image
Graphics2D graphics = screenshot.createGraphics();
// We make the screenshot slightly transparent
graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.7f)); 
view.print(graphics); // takes the screenshot
graphics.dispose();
```

2) Paint the screenshot on the receiving view. When the drag gesture is recognized, find a way to make the screenshot available to the receiving view or one of its ancestor (you could make it available on the frame or its content pane, depending on where you want to make the screenshot drag available) and paint the image within the paint method. Something like this:

a. Make the screenshot available:

```
capturedDraggedNodeImage = view.getScreenshot(); // Transfer the screenshot
dragOrigin = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), e.getDragOrigin(), view); // locate the point where the click was made
```

b. As the mouse is dragged, update the location of the screenshot

```
// Assuming 'e' is a DropTargetDragEvent and 'this' is where you want to paint
// Convert the event point to this component coordinates
capturedNodeLocation = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(((DropTarget) e.getSource()).getComponent(), e.getLocation(), this);
// offset the location by the original point of drag on the palette element view
capturedNodeLocation.x -= dragOrigin.x;
capturedNodeLocation.y -= dragOrigin.y;
// Invoke repaint
repaint(capturedNodeLocation.x, capturedNodeLocation.y, 
   capturedDraggedNodeImage.getWidth(), capturedDraggedNodeImage.getHeight());
```

c. paint the screenshot in paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2.drawImage(capturedDraggedNodeImage, capturedNodeLocation.x, 
        capturedNodeLocation.y, capturedDraggedNodeImage.getWidth(), 
        capturedDraggedNodeImage.getHeight(), this);
}
```

Instead of calling repaint() and perform the painting in the paint() method, you could invoke paintImmediately() as the mouse moves but the rendering will be a lot poorer and you could observe some flickering, so I would not recommend that option. Using paint() and repaint() provides a better user experience and a smooth rendering.

Answer (score 1):

If I hear you well, you are creating a graphical editor of some sort, with drag and drop of elements, and you want to create an effect during that drag and drop?

If so, you basically need to create a ghost of the object you're dragging and attach it to the move of the mouse. Easier said than done, of course, but you get the gist.
So what you need is to take the image of what you're dragging (it shouldn't be too much trouble) and move it according to the position of the mouse (think of substracting the relative position of the mouse cursor in the object you're dragging).

But I think that kind of code is available somewhere. I'd advise you to look that up :

http://free-the-pixel.blogspot.fr/2010/04/ghost-drag-and-drop-over-multiple.html

http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Drag-and-Drop/Translucent-Drag-and-Drop/

Hope that helps you!